# how to hide checkbox and checkbox text using javascript in web forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, webforms

I am working on web forms and writing a piece of javascript to hide checkbox and its text but only checkbox is getting hidden Text is still showing the way it was showing earlier.

Here is my view code

```html
<table style="width: 60%">
     <tr>
        <td class="td_150px">
            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkEnddate" runat="server" CssClass="label" Text="End On"
                              onclick="EndSchedule();" TextAlign="Left"/>
         </td>

    </tr>
</table>
```

So here is my javascript code
on click of a radio button i am using below code to hide the checkbox and text but only checkbox is hidden not text.

```
 var chkEnddate= document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_chkEnddate");
    chkEnddate.style.display = "none";
```

Can anybody help me to hide checkbox and it's text at the same time using javascript. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show html generated of your checkbox ? where is text ?

Answer (score 2):

place the checkbox in the `div` element and try to hide that `div` element

```
<td class="td_150px">
 <div id="chkEnddateBox">
   <asp:CheckBox ID="chkEnddate" runat="server" CssClass="label" Text="End On"
   onclick="EndSchedule();" TextAlign="Left" />
 </div>
</td>
```

and in the javascript

```
var chkEnddate= document.getElementById("chkEnddateBox");
chkEnddate.style.display = "none";
```